# Have a String name as an Id with JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

What I want to do is to change my id from a float to a string.

I have this entity that represents a group:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="group")
public class GroupEntity {

@Id
private String name;

@ManyToMany
private List<UserEntity> users;
```

And in my bootstrap file I have this:

```
    Password p = new Password("test");

    UserEntity user = new UserEntity("pedro", p);
    List<UserEntity> users = new ArrayList<UserEntity>();

    List<GroupEntity> groupEntities=new ArrayList<GroupEntity>();

    users.add(user);

    GroupEntity r1 = new GroupEntity("Integrations");

    groupEntities.add(r1);
    user.getGroups().add(r1); //this user has a group

    r1.setUsers(users);  // this group has a user
```

My UserEntity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String name;
```

With that, my program works with no problem, you can see the groups are saved with the id being their name:

[image]

But when I change the UserEntity class from that to this one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {

@Id 
private String name;
```

This error appears:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'bootstrap': Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable
>   to find com.alert.interservices.uaa.RoleEntity with id Integrations;
>   nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable
>   to find com.alert.interservices.uaa.RoleEntity with id Integrations

I think the problem is with the id but don´t know how to solve it.

Update 1-application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Comment: I think the field `name` of table `user` must be a Primary Key to use the `@Id`

Comment: looks like you should also change your database structure making the `name` a primary key and drop old primary key `id`. Because relational databases has a predefined schema you should migrate the schema along with the changing the ORM mappings

Comment: Do you also have a RoleEntity that needs to be updated in some way? How are you creating the DB schema? Is it being created by Hibernate with create-drop?

Comment: I am using h2 and spring,the configurations are on my applications.properties file, i updated my question with that

Comment: you have to put in application.properties - spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

Comment: I put that and it still didnt work

Comment: The problem is in your databasa user table schema, you should make name the primary key and delete the ID field or constraint or whatever you have before making your Entities.

Comment: But I dont have the ID field on the userEntity anymore

Comment: I think  `user` is reserved name in Postgres you can change that name to `users` may solve your problem

Comment: didn´t work either

Comment: also add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true` two both line create table based on entity every time you restart your server

Comment: didn't work either

Comment: did create a new table? and post your spring configuration

Comment: How can I verify that?

Comment: The program closes when it starts,I dont know if I can check that

Answer (score 0):

first, yes you can use String as an Id type. but I think your problem is you have edited the entities without removing the old database, so prevent that issue you must change your strategy in the persistence unit to drop and create, because you are using spring data you can use:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

But you could use it just for test, but in production environment you must switch it to  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update.` 
Note: the `update` option just add columns but never delete columns.

Comment: and how tdo I do that with h2 and spring?

Comment: I did this ( spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop ) on my application.properties and it didnt work

Comment: Hello, sorry for your wait, yes you can use  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop but just during the test in production environments you switch it to : spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: So try to drop the database manually, and re-run the project.